# Custom jQuery Slider with Sub Category Images

Tags: slider

I want to create a jQuery slider with the following functionality:

- main image should slide wi
- thumbnails carousel with left and right arrow.

When click on thumbnail a array of image should show on large viewport with slide effect and caption of the image will in fade effect.

Comment: ok, so go ahead and create.

Comment: Use  - http://galleria.io/ or http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-slick-auto-playing-featured-content-slider/